# Can't do performance testing with license file via commandline

Tags: performance-testing, neoload

I want to perform a performance testing with Neoload installed in my linux server. I have noGui, so I want to use a commandline and I'm using this one according to [the following documentation](https://documentation.tricentis.com/neoload/9.0/en/WebHelp/#643.htm#o41413) :

```
./NeoLoadCmd -noGUI -project /var/jenkins_home/neoload_projects/neoload-training/neoload-training.nlp -launch jpetstore_nominal -leaseLicense "[LICENSE_ID]:10:2"
```

This is the output of the command :

`neoload-training.nlp file has been found in /var/jenkins_home/neoload_projects/neoload-training. Logging to /var/jenkins_home/.neotys/neoload/v2023.3/logs, as user: jenkins Error leasing license. Unknown Error. No nts host specified for license server. An error occurred during Controller initialization: com.neotys.license.data.n: Unknown Error. No nts host specified for license server. -- Error caused by : Unknown Error. No nts host specified for license server.`

I have a license problem and I need to specify a nts host.

I tried to find the Neoload license file and replace it with a good license according to [this documentation](https://www.setgetweb.com/p/neoload/630.htm) :

`Go to the License Management section of the Neotys website to activate the license and retrieve file "license-activated.lic". Rename the file into "license.lic". Copy it in the NeoLoad user folder to overwrite the existing file.`

and I still have the same issue.

My question is, since using license file is deprecated, is it possible to pass through NeoLoad Web to generate token and connect this token to your NeoLoad controller to perform a performance testing with the commandline ?